# Message is undefined

Tags: javascript, discord

ogloszenie.command.js file

```
const { RichEmbed, Channel } = require("discord.js")
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    
    module.exports = {
      name: "ogloszenie",
      description: "Wysyła ogłoszenie",
    
      run(msg, args) {
    
        const { channel } = msg
        
        let announcemessage = message.content.match(/(?<=announce ).*$/)[0];
        let finalmessage = announcemessage.toUpperCase();
    
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor("RED")
        .setTitle(" • OGŁOSZENIE", "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/800088813774438440/800089290972463114/7921185_0.jpg")
        .setFooter("el cartel de medelline", "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/800088813774438440/800089290972463114/7921185_0.jpg")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setDescription(finalmessage);
    
        channel.send(embed)
        
    
      }
    }
```

command.handler.js file

```
const { readdirSync } = require("fs")

const { prefix } = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.js")

const { Collection } = require("discord.js")

const ascii = require("ascii-table")

const table = new ascii().setHeading("Command", "Load status")

module.exports = (client) => {
  // Collections
  client.commands = new Collection()

  const commandFiles = readdirSync(__dirname + "/../commands").filter((file) =>
    file.endsWith(".command.js"),
  )

  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(__dirname + `/../commands/${file}`)

    if (command.name) {
      client.commands.set(command.name, command)
      table.addRow(file, "✅")
    } else {
      table.addRow(file, "❌  -> missing 'name'!")
      continue
    }
  }

  console.log(table.toString())

  client.on("message", (msg) => {
    const { author, guild } = msg

    // Check if user is a bot
    if (author.bot || !guild) {
      return
    }

    // Ignore messages without prefix
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return

    const args = msg.content
      .slice(prefix.length)
      .trim()
      .split(/ +/g)

    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    // Check if commands exist
    if (!client.commands.has(cmd)) return

    try {
      client.commands.get(cmd).run(msg, args)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      msg.reply("there was an error trying to execute that command!")
    }
  })
}
```

console log

C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0\src\commands\ogloszenie.command.js:15
let announcemessage = message.content.match(/(?<=announce ).*$/)[0];
^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0\src\commands\ogloszenie.command.js:15:29)
at Client. (C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0\src\handlers\command.handler.js:55:32)
at Client.emit (node:events:329:20)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:329:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
PS C:\Users\profe\Desktop\DiscordBot-1.6.0>

how to fix it?

Comment: By the way looks like you're using discord.js v11, you should switch to v12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `msg` instead of `message`:

```js
const { RichEmbed, Channel } = require("discord.js")
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    
    module.exports = {
      name: "ogloszenie",
      description: "Wysyła ogłoszenie",
    
      run(msg, args) {
    
        const { channel } = msg
        
        let announcemessage = msg.content.match(/(?<=announce ).*$/)[0];
        let finalmessage = announcemessage.toUpperCase();
    
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor("RED")
        .setTitle(" • OGŁOSZENIE", "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/800088813774438440/800089290972463114/7921185_0.jpg")
        .setFooter("el cartel de medelline", "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/800088813774438440/800089290972463114/7921185_0.jpg")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setDescription(finalmessage);
    
        channel.send(embed)
        
    
      }
    }
```